# Fast unpack of SAM flag bitfield to named symbols

Tags: python, hash-map, iteration

```
def sam_flag_explainer(flag:int):
    """
    Intepret sam flag and make a flag-explained-dictionary. 

    """
    try:
        # Convert sam flags to binary format, like 0101001
        # flag is a integer.
        flag_binary = "{0:b}".format(flag)
    except Exception as err:
        if int(flag) == flag:
            flag = int(flag)
            flag_binary = "{0:b}".format(flag)
        else:
            print(f"{flag=}")
            raise ValueError from err

    flag_template = {
        "read_paired":False,
        "read_mapped_in_proper_pair":False,
        "read_unmapped":False,
        "mate_unmapped":False,
        "read_reverse_strand":False,
        "mate_reverse_strand":False,
        "first_in_pair":False,
        "second_in_pair":False,
        "not_primary_alignment":False,
        "read_fails_platform/vendor_quality_checks":False,
        "read_is_PCR_or_optical_duplicate":False,
        "supplementary_alignment":False,
    }

    for k, f in zip(flag_template.keys(), flag_binary[::-1]): # should intepret the flag from back.
        if int(f) == 1:
            flag_template[k] = True
    
    return flag_template
```

The code is the above.

Schematically, this function does:

> Convert integer into binary number -> Read it from the back -> Modify the value of the key based on binary number element.

This function is called a lot of times in my program.

And this function is slow and it accounts for a large percentage of the overall execution time.

How could I make this faster?

Comment: What do you mean by read it from the back?

Comment: @KimiM Now that I think about it, I don't think that's necessary.

Comment: If you are trying to convert the integer to binary, you can use bin().

Comment: The question title should be what the code does, not what your question is. Do you have tests showing how the function is called?

Comment: Also, you could use `int('0b(what your binary int is)', 2)` to convert back.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would prefer an implementation that is simple, built-in, type-safe, and explicit (the original implementation is arguably explicit, but not simple or type-safe; and whereas it does use built-ins it doesn't necessarily take advantage of the right ones).

This is faster, but if it isn't fast enough, you'd be in diminishing returns and need to re-evaluate your choice of using Python. Justin Chang's brute-force cache method does technically work and is quite fast, but is also higher-complexity, has less structure, and takes up 32 kB of memory; it's up to you to choose which trade-offs are more important.

`__slots__` has at least three advantages - it improves class performance; it rejects arbitrary member assignment; and it gets the class halfway to type safety (defining which members are there, but not their types). Whereas it does require duplication of member names, as Matthieu M has suggested this can be reused to form `_fields_` in runtime.

A note about type safety: sadly, the `ctypes` machinery doesn't really produce type-safe structs in a strict sense unless you go out of your way and add a hint for every member as e.g. `read_paired: int`. It's unclear if this is of value to you.

Also, having a `/` in a member name is not a great idea (even though it does technically work with `ctypes`), so I have replaced this with another underscore.

```py
import ctypes
import struct


class SAMFlags(ctypes.LittleEndianStructure):
    __slots__ = (
        'read_paired',
        'read_mapped_in_proper_pair',
        'read_unmapped',
        'mate_unmapped',
        'read_reverse_strand',
        'mate_reverse_strand',
        'first_in_pair',
        'second_in_pair',
        'not_primary_alignment',
        'read_fails_platform_vendor_quality_checks',
        'read_is_PCR_or_optical_duplicate',
        'supplementary_alignment',
    )

    _fields_ = [(name, ctypes.c_uint8, 1) for name in __slots__]

    def __init__(self, flags: int) -> None:
        struct.pack_into('<H', self, 0, flags)
```

With this quick hack to do timing:

```py
measures = []
for method in (SAMFlags, sam_flag_explainer_op):
    for bits_set in range(13):
        flags = (1 << bits_set) - 1
        def run():
            return method(flags)
        for _ in range(1_000):
            measures.append([
                method.__name__,
                bits_set,
                timeit.timeit(stmt=run, number=100)/100,
            ])
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=measures,
    columns=['method', 'bits', 'time']
)
seaborn.lineplot(data=df, x='bits', y='time', hue='method')
plt.show()
```

we get:

[image: timing]

Unsurprisingly, the original method exhibits a clear O(n) in the number of bits set in the flag.

Comment: It is possible to use constants for the field names? Would still need to type the constant twice, but at least spelling mistakes would become "compilation" errors.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Great idea! In essence, `__slots__` already has the constants, so we can just use that.

Comment: "**Note**: It’s tempting to calculate mean and standard deviation from the result vector and report these. ... In a typical case, the lowest value gives a lower bound for how fast your machine can run the given code snippet; higher values in the result vector are typically not caused by variability in Python’s speed, but by other processes interfering with your timing accuracy. So the min() of the result is probably the only number you should be interested in." https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.Timer.repeat

Answer (score 5):

There are `2^F` possible flag configurations, where `F` is the number of fields. You can precompute each configuration and store the cached values in a list. To retrieve the relevant configuration, index into the list based on the least significant bits of `flag` (the remainder `mod 2^F`):

```py
flag_template = {
    "read_paired": False,
    "read_mapped_in_proper_pair": False,
    "read_unmapped": False,
    "mate_unmapped": False,
    "read_reverse_strand": False,
    "mate_reverse_strand": False,
    "first_in_pair": False,
    "second_in_pair": False,
    "not_primary_alignment": False,
    "read_fails_platform/vendor_quality_checks": False,
    "read_is_PCR_or_optical_duplicate": False,
    "supplementary_alignment": False
}
flag_template_keys = flag_template.keys()
flag_field_count = len(flag_template_keys)
flag_field_combos = (2 ** flag_field_count)


def compute_explainer(flag: int):
    flag_binary = "{0:b}".format(flag)
    copy_template = dict(flag_template)  # make a copy
    for k, f in zip(flag_template_keys, flag_binary[::-1]):
        copy_template[k] = (int(f) == 1)  # set true / false
    return copy_template


cached_explainers = [0] * flag_field_combos  # precompute
for i in range(flag_field_combos):
    cached_explainers[i] = compute_explainer(i)


def sam_flag_explainer(flag: int):
    return cached_explainers[int(flag) % flag_field_combos]
```

This ought to catch most errors because `int(flag)` will fail in similar cases. The only edge case I can find is that the revised version gladly accepts negative numbers. You can write a small test suite to compare speeds and verify the output is identical for nonnegative `flag` values:

```py
import time
start_time = time.time()
for i in range(10000000):
    sam_flag_explainer(i)
print("time elapsed: {:.2f}s".format(time.time() - start_time))
for i in [3, 17, 234343434]:
    print(sam_flag_explainer(i))
print(sam_flag_explainer("dfdfdf"))
```

Here's the time difference for the testing suites on my computer (Python 3.10):

```
original time elapsed: 57.75s
revised time elapsed: 2.60s
```

Hope that helps. Good work on making the question clear.

**EDIT:** Reinderien makes good points regarding the broader context in which this function may be used. Based on the use case, you may need to weigh tradeoffs. For example, one use case might be converting from 1 million flags to a table with 1 million rows and the fields as columns. In that case, I would suggest finding a way to vectorize the operation, taking in all the flags at once, so that you can speed up the heavy lifting. Another use case might be that some downstream function / API call / utility requires arguments with field names. In that case, you might be able to adjust the downstream process to use the flag directly. Finally, you might be able to inspect the upstream process (whatever is creating these flags) and configure it to output the explained form directly. Good luck.

Comment: It's a neat idea, and brute force does sometimes have its applications. Does your _revised time elapsed_ include the time for pre-computation? If not, what is it? It would also be good to mention the LRU cache approach.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. If I include the precomputation time, I get 3.26s. To my knowledge, SAM bitwise flags are a fairly common standard and I would expect F = 12 to hold for most use cases. But if F does increase a lot, I agree that a more sophisticated caching strategy may be useful.